# react mapping image point and setting style

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, canvas

I have a requirement where on clicking on a human body image I have to display a circle on that body part. I'm able to render the circle but not on the body part. And if I scroll and click on the same body part the circle renders in a different place. Here's the example.

[CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-dust-05p0tm?file=/src/App.tsx)

This also creates an issue with different screen sizes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`event.target.getBoundingClientRect()` returns the size of an element and its position relative to the viewport. And `event.target.naturalWidth` and `event.target.naturalHeight` provides the natural width and height of `<img/>` (original pixels wide)

so you can calculate absolute position of circle which will be placed on image by `event.target.natural(width or height) / rect.(width or height)`

**Example**

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

import human_body from "./images/human body.png";
import circle from "./images/hover-circle.png";

export default function App() {
  const [circlePosition, setCirclePosition] = useState({ left: 0, top: 0 });

  const imgClick = (event: any) => {
    const rect = event.target.getBoundingClientRect();
    const scaleX = event.target.naturalWidth / rect.width;
    const scaleY = event.target.naturalHeight / rect.height;
    const left = event.nativeEvent.offsetX * scaleX - 20; 
    const top = event.nativeEvent.offsetY * scaleY - 20;
    setCirclePosition({ left, top });
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        {circlePosition.left > 0 && circlePosition.top > 0 && (
          <img
            src={circle}
            alt="hover-body"
            style={{
              width: 50,
              height: 50,
              left: circlePosition.left,
              top: circlePosition.top,
              position: "absolute",
              zIndex: 10
            }}
          />
        )}
        <img id="human_body" onClick={imgClick} src={human_body} alt="body" />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: It somewhat solves the issue, but with different screen sizes it messes things up

Answer (score 0):

I made some dits to your code, you can cehck if this works for you.

[Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/flamboyant-cerf-1kb6wf?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)